# Are margins relative to the current element?

Tags: html, css, font-size

Lets say I have the following code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>
        Hello World
      </h1>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>

body{
  // make 1em equivalent to 10px when browser default is 16px 
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

header{
  font-size: 1em;
}

header h1{
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

If the browser's default font-size is 16px, then our h1 will be 30px. I was hoping that the margin below my h1 would be 33% of the font-size but for some reason it is also 30px. Just like the font-size. I clearly specify that it should be 1em.

I understand that em's are relative to the parent container. Are margins relative to the current element? i.e. if font-size of the h1 is set to 4em (40px), then does a 1em margin automatically become 40px too? Is this the expected behaviour? Should I be saying `margin-bottom: 0.33em`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that [1em is equal to the **current font size**.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp) So if we had this:

```
<header style="font-size:10px;">
<h1 style="font-size:2em; padding:1em;">
Hello World
</h1>
<p style="padding:1em;">
The world is a happy place
</p>
</header>
```

The padding for `h1` would be 20px and the padding for `p` would be 10px.

If you are new to ems, I just remembered this article that I highly recommend that talks about creating webpages using ems: [Fluid Grids](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/)

Comment: The `rem` (root em) unit may also be of interest to you. It is being introduced as part of CSS3. See [this article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem)

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that em's are relative to the parent container

No. em's are relative the current font size. So defining a font size in ems is circular. Typographically speaking, you should define font sizes in *points,* not pixels, then you gain resolution-independence, and then define margins and widths and indents &c in ems.